# Problems Creating new project

Tags: android

I have download some example and put it under c:\android\WifiDemo. Now when I'm trying to create a new project I choose at the wizard "create project from existing resouce" the I choose the above folder and itt gives the following error: Invalid project description". when I look at details it gives  C:\android2\WiFiDemo overlaps the location of another project: 'WiFiDemo'

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,
Nahum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try importing it instead.  If you are using Eclipse that is File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace.

Answer (score 4):

Use Import Wizard of Eclipse.

Just Go To

> File>Import>General>Existing Projects
>   into Workspace

Now specify your folder C:\android\WifiDemo

You can also copy that in your workspace also.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.If you think my answer is correct then you must accept the answer.